# Defining the default value for a ULONG& optional parameter as 0

Tags: c++, methods, compiler-errors, default-parameters

The following function declaration:

```
void Foo:DoSomething( ULONG &Count = 0) { .... }
```

Results in the following compile time error

`error C2440: default argument cannot convert from 'int' to 'ULONG &'`

What is the correct way of creating the signature so that when there is no parameter provided for `Count` its value will be zero.

Comment: @icepack sorry about that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're taking a non-const reference to Count, so it can't be assigned by default with r-value.

Use

`void Foo:DoSomething( const ULONG &Count = 0) { .... }`

`void Foo:DoSomething( ULONG Count = 0) { .... }`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this for non-const references.  A reference is pointing to an address in memory.  Unless you specifically need reference semantics, I'd recommend just passing by value.